# Spring Security and Azure - After restart, app tries to reauthorize, but Azure's redirect to the redirect-uri results in 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a Spring Boot 2 webapp.  It uses Azure AD for user authentication (using authorization-code flow and delegated permissions), making use of Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 login support.  It also tries to access Microsoft Graph resources.  However, it doesn't use Microsoft's Azure library for Spring.

For the most part, the code below works as expected.  (I'm running it locally.)

```java
@Autowired
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

@RequestMapping("/aboutMe")
public String aboutMe(Model model,
                      @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
    String accessTokenValue = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = buildRestTemplate(accessTokenValue);

    String user = restTemplate.getForObject("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", String.class);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "pages/me";
}

private RestTemplate buildRestTemplate(String accessTokenValue) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.additionalInterceptors(
        new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] bytes,
                                ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

                request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessTokenValue);

                return execution.execute(request, bytes);
            }
        }).build();

    return restTemplate;
}
```

However, the following test case works as expected only until the app is restarted.

#### Test case

1. Open a browser for the first time and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/aboutMe`.
2. The browser will go to the Microsoft login page.  Log in using Azure AD credentials.
3. The browser will then go to the `/aboutMe` page.
4. Shut down the app, then start it again.
5. Don't close the browser.  Leave it open.
6. Try to navigate again to `http://localhost:8080/aboutMe`.

#### Actual outcome

1. The browser is redirected to the Microsoft `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint.
2. The Microsoft `authorize` request then redirects the browser to the app's `redirect-uri`, which in this case begins with `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure`.
3. The app responds with a 404 - Not Found.

#### Expected outcome

Either:

- Azure AD should display the login page again and ask the user to authenticate again, and then have the app correctly handle it;
- **or** Either the app or Spring, or both, should handle the redirect request, instead of returning a 404.

#### Investigation

The 404 seems to be due to the fact that the app's `redirect-uri` isn't always "listening," particularly in this case.

In the above controller code, the `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure")` causes Spring Security's `OAuth2AuthorizedClientArgumentResolver` to throw a `ClientAuthorizationRequiredException` because it can't find a `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`--which is what we'd expect, given that the app was restarted.

The `ClientAuthorizationRequiredException` then causes `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` to redirect the browser to Azure to request for authorization.

However, instead of asking for the user's credentials, Azure redirects the browser to the app's `redirect-uri`, with what seems to be a new authorization.  (I'm assuming it's because the browser sent cookies with its request, which Azure deems to still be valid.)

#### Finally, my question

What's the best way to deal with this kind of situation, to avoid confusing the user?  Sure, I can always tell the users to just close all browser windows and try again.  However, this behavior on its own isn't clean at all from a user's viewpoint.

I believe the `/login/oauth2/code/azure` endpoint is normally handled by Spring Security filter(s), so I'm not sure how to intercept that.

Maybe a solution is to have the app clear all its cookies in the browser on startup?  But what about Azure's cookies?

Comment: Could explain the annotation `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure")` a bit more. I'm implementing a similar service to use the ms graph api. What does argument passed to the annotation apply to?

Comment: @JosephFreeman - The `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient` is essentially a shortcut to having to manually get an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`.  The alternative would be to use the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`.  When Spring sees this annotation, it will attempt to retrieve an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` for you, using the properties of the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration` provider you specify (here, `azure`), and then inject it as the parameter.  Reference:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-registered-authorized-client

Comment: What the user sees when you use `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient` is that if the user is not already authenticated, or if the user's token has expired, the browser will be redirected to the OAuth 2 or OpenID Connect provider's login page.  Upon successful authentication, the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` (which contains the access and refresh tokens) will be injected into the method.

The parameter to the annotation ("azure" or "google" or some other name) is to make sure that Spring uses the correct OAuth2 provider, especially in the case that you've configured your app for multiple providers.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This explains why spring was using a default oauth url instead of the one I defined in the properties via `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.token-uri`because I had the client name specified as the argument in the annotation. What I'm attempting to do is create a spring service that integrates with Microsoft Planner. I've followed the azure spring examples on github but they don't give nearly enough information for  implementation.

Comment: I have stack question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047044/spring-boot-v2-1-6-microsoft-azure-ad-graph-planner-integration-server-side

I'm going to modified it, I've made past my original issue. It would be awesome if you can provide any additional help that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding `.oauth2Client()` to the Spring Security configuration.  Here's the working configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/web/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
            .and()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl(azureLogoutUri)
            .permitAll()
        // Without the oauth2Client(), the 404 happens
        .and()
        .oauth2Client();
}
```

The addition of `.oauth2Client()` causes Spring to add to the security filter chain a second `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` and a `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`.

I had erroneously assumed that `oauth2Client()` wasn't needed.  That appears to be true only if it doesn't find a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.