# Spring Boot (v2.1.6) Microsoft Planner Integration

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a Spring Boot service that integrates the web API for Microsoft Planner. I've created an app registration in Azure and granted the permissions for Groups.Read.All and Users.Read.All (delegated).

What I am currently attempting to implement is server side oauth authentication. As of now, the `authorization-grant-type` that I am using is `client_credentials`. With the below WebSecurityConfiguration I am able to make a request to endpoint that I created called `/test`. The endpoint is a `GET` request that has an argument `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient`.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    public class AzureSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oAuth2UserService;

        @Autowired
        public AzureSecurityConfiguration(OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oAuth2UserService) {
            this.oAuth2UserService = oAuth2UserService;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

With that, when the request is made Spring will make the necessary request to Microsofts OAuth endpoints to get an access token.

When using this token to make a request (w/Postman) to a Microsoft Planner API endpoint, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{username}/planner/tasks` I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "some randomly generated id",
            "date": "time stamp of request"
        }
    }
}
```

The scope defined that gets me this far is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. At this point I'm sure why this works but when defining the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/users.read.all` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/users.read.all` does not work, and gets me an error stating that the provided value for the input parameter is not valid.

Groups.Read.All and Users.Read.All are the API permissions that I have granted to the app registration in Azure so I am not sure why that fails.

My ultimate goal is project is to leverage Microsoft's Graph API to create, delete, update MS Planner Tasks for a given user. I would like the service to log the user in instead of the user having to manually log into Office 360. It would be nice to make it seamless to the user.

Any help would be most appreciated.

SIDE NOTE: I've already looked through the azure github at the samples they provide and they were helpful to a certain extent.

UPDATE:
I've noticed that in the JSON that contains the access token, there's a property called `principalName` which it is set to `"anonymousUser"`. I'm thinking this is why the access token does not have the permissions to make request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user.name}/planner/tasks`.

Has anyone seen this before, and is there a way to set the `principalName` to an actual username?

Comment: YOu may want to try https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to figure out if your account has the right permissions to access the planner API. Also are you trying to get other users planner info? From memory you should be using the `me` inconjuction with the access token for user specific stuff

Comment: @DarrenForsy Thanks for responding! Yes, I would be getting the planner task of other users. I've tried getting my own task using `/v1.0/me/planner/tasks` with the current token I'm getting `You do not have permission to view this directory`

Comment: I haven't played with the client credentials flow using Spring Security 5.  But I suspect `principalName` is set to `anonymousUser` because the token is obtained using the client credentials flow, which isn't tied to a particular user.  If you haven't tried it already, confirm that the entire flow (getting a token, then calling the Planner endpoint) works on Postman.

Comment: @rdguam Thank you for the response! Yes I've attempted the following planner request using the `access_token` that I am currently getting: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jf40383/planner/tasks` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks`. Both request using the same `access_token` gets me the following error: `401 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalide credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied`

Comment: @JosephFreeman - If the behavior you described was entirely observed on Postman (ie, not involving Spring at all), then it seems to me that it likely is a permissions issue in Azure. I'd recommend checking again your app's permissions (i.e., for Planner tasks: `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`), as well as granting administrator consent for them. It looks like the Planner task endpoint requires both the signed-in user's and an admin's consent. Also, I've found the new Azure Portal UI to be a little weird sometimes, so you might also want to try removing then re-adding the permissions.

Comment: @rdguam I have double check my permissions and they are correct, and yes the Azure Portal is a bit odd since the UI just randomly changes lol. I think I've come to the conclusion that this will either not work or not the right route to be taking. Looks like the will be a need for client side implementation using adal.js. I wanted to make it seamless to the user doesn't seem like it possible. Thank you for your help!!